# Adding Target Audiences Programmatically

Tags: 2013, development, sharepoint-server

I am trying to programmatically add target audiences to a webpart in SP 2013.
Code below.

```
    SPServiceContext sc = SPServiceContext.GetContext(newSite);
    AudienceManager audienceManager = new AudienceManager(sc);
    AudienceCollection ac = audienceManager.Audiences;
    Audience va = ac.Create("Volunteer Approvers", "Volunteer Approvers");
    Audience sa = ac.Create("Staff Approvers", "Staff Approvers");

    wp.AuthorizationFilter = string.Format("{0},{1};;;;{2},{3},{4}", audienceManager.GetAudience("Staff Approvers").AudienceID, audienceManager.GetAudience("Volunteer Approvers").AudienceID, groupVolApprovers.Name, groupAdmin.Name, volunteers.Name);
manager.AddWebPart(wp,"Left",2);
manager.SaveChanges(wp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Under Central Admin --> Manage Service Applications --> User Profile Service Application (Select, not click) --> Administrators (in ribbon). Make sure the user that the app pool runs under is in the list and has Manage Audiences permission.

I had to do this because I had the above code in runwithelevatedprivileges.

2. Surround the above code - you need to get rid of the HttpContext.Current.

So..

```
var tmp = HttpContext.Current;
HttpContext.Current = null;

... Code to create audiences and set the AuthorizationFilter string ...

HttpContext.Current = tmp
```

This article explained why you need to do that.

http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/access-denied-error-when-retrieving-user-profiles-count-from-sharepoint

Another one that helped me format the AuthorizationFilter string
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee906649%28v=office.14%29.aspx

I hope this helps someone because I spent 2 days trying to figure this out.